# Modify Override the Views Filter Criteria Programaticly

Tags: 7, views

I have the following view being called in my code with views_get_view() and I then try to modify the filter called **usershare** to admin instead of the default that I have set in my view. But it doesn't seem to override my view output. What am I doing wrong here? I noticed that some examples use **pre_execute()** and some just use **excute()**. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

```
      $view2 = views_get_view('flag_lists_user_lists_public', FALSE);
      $view2->set_display('default');

$view2->display_handler->display->display_options['filters']['usershare']['value'] = 'admin';

      $view2->pre_execute();
      $output .= $view2->render();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter() :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if($form['#id'] == 'flag_lists_user_lists_public') {
    $form['usershare']['#value'] = 'admin';
  }
}
```